XYZ Tile renders on workscreen but not on the layout and won´t print
I am currently analyzing activity data and discovered that it's possible to add Strava heatmaps to QGIS. I follewed this tutorial "https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Strava" and the magic happend, heatmap appeared in front of me. BUT!, my happiness was short lived when I discovered the this XYZ Tiles strava layer won´t even appear on the print layout. 
QGIS version
3.30.2-'s-Hertogenbosch

Please do not post statements of urgency. They are a shortcut to downvotes.

Please provide as much information as possible like the extent of your layout, the export properties including resolution. I have imported Strava Heatmaps as an XYZ Layer in QGIS (3.28) and it shows up/exports fine as a layout
